# Is it posslible to mmap tcp client fd?

Tags: c++, tcp, mmap

I'm trying to mmap tcp client using following code:

```
sockaddr_in addr,peer;
int server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

int value = 1;
assert(setsockopt(server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &value, sizeof(value)) != -1 );
assert(setsockopt(server, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &value, sizeof(value)) != -1 );

addr.sin_port = htons(8080);
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
assert(bind(server, (sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr)) != -1 );
assert(listen(server, 5) != -1 );

socklen_t len;
int client = accept(server, (sockaddr *)&peer,&len);
assert(client != -1);

char *ip = inet_ntoa(peer.sin_addr);
int port = htons(peer.sin_port);
printf("Client accepted: %s:%d\n",ip,port );

auto mapped = (char*) mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED , client, 0);
assert(mapped !=  (char*) -1); //mmap returns -1
char *str = "Hello client\n";
memcpy(mapped, str, strlen(str)); // send message to client
```

But mmap returns -1 when client connects.
So is there another way how to mmap client fd or is not possible.

Comment: mmap is about mapping a file, not a data stream (i.e. network stream). You also cannot seek on a data stream either, only on a file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why is it not possible to use mmap with socket fd as an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873956/why-is-it-not-possible-to-use-mmap-with-socket-fd-as-an-argument)